# How can I prove this property of convolution with a Gaussian?

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

Using the shift property of the Fourier transform, $e^{-ix_0k}G(k)$ is the Fourier transform of $g(x-x_0)$.

In my case, $g$ is a Gaussian function $g(x-x_0)=e^{-\sigma (x-x_0)^2}$ , so $G(k)$ is also a rescaled Gaussian.

I have reason to believe that for arbitrary (differentiable) $F$

$F(k)*(e^{-ix_0k}G(k))=e^{ix_0k}(F(k)*G(k))$

where $*$ represents convolution.

But my proof of this is long-winded. Likely unnecessarily so. I want to confirm by some other means that this is the case. It looks like a simple result, and I feel there must be a more obvious way to demonstrate it.

So my question is simply:Is it true that
$F(k)*(e^{-ix_0k}G(k))=e^{ix_0k}(F(k)*G(k))$  ? And if so, how can it be proven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the result is not true. Since there is a one-one mapping between a function and it's Fourier transform, (In the proceeding transformations, trailing constants like factors of $2 \pi$ have been omitted and the --> symbol means taking a Fourier transform)

If,
$$ g(x)  --> G(k) \quad  \text{and}$$
$$ f(x)  -->  F(k)$$
then,
$$f(x)g(x - x_0)   --> F(k)*(e^{-ix_0k}G(k)) \tag{1}$$
However, the other function has inverse FT
$$\delta(x+x_0)*(f(x).g(x)) --> e^{ix_ok}(F(k)*G(k)) \tag{2}$$
Where $\delta$ is the delta function/Impulse function

If we define $h(x) = g(x)f(x)$, the LHS reduces to 
$$h(x+x_0) = f(x+x_0)g(x+x_0)$$
Which is not the same as the LHS of (1)

Comment: Nicely spotted! Seems you are correct... I'll have to search for the flaw in my work. Thanks!